# WordPress - AdSense Ad only in currently displayed section

Tags: wordpress, adsense, shortcode

i have an important question about the wordpress shortcut "sections" ([sections][section]Content 1[/section]...[/sections]) in WordPress..

I want only the currently selected section to display google ads.

As you might know, google only allows 3 ads to be displayed at the same time.
And my page will constantly grow, so there will be 2 ads - 1 before the content, 1 after the content, but if a user needs material between those two, he wouldn't see the ad.

So i'm just trying to figure out, how to display an ad in the currently display section.

Comment: From where you are fetching your ads? They must have provide you some documentation. Use that & add it to appropriate template.

Comment: My template is called "photography" and my wordpress installation is a self-hosted, multisite network with individual domains.
I'm not that pro at php, i have the basics and anyways i'm a developer, but i need to know where to look for or what to do :/..

I think there must be any kind of event or something like that, which determines whether one element is selected etc.

You could take a look at my page [link]http://www.robbelroot.de[/link]

PS: You need to turn on german language, english isn't ready yet.

Comment: I found some information, but im not sure if this is a standard plugin/thingy which is installed by default in wordpress:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode/

At least im using code like the first given sample in this article.

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/wordpress-shortcode-for-google-adsense/